# Can't create migration because EntityFramework.Design package isn't recognized

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I installed *EntityFrameworkCore.Design* running the following.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -Version 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10
```

It seems to be installed and I can see the following in VS.

[image: [image]]

However, when I try to create a migration using

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init
```

I get quite some time waiting followed by the error below.

> Your startup project 'Web' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

When I checked the *Web.proj* file, I get to see the following section.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I ensure that the computer sees the package?

Comment: Do you have other projects there in that solution

Comment: @CodeNameJack Nope. I had initially a few but realized that the complexity was waaaay too hight and removed them. Are you thinking that VS somehow stumbled and kept the other references? I checked the SLN file and didn't notice anything particular.

Comment: It happens sometimes that we try to apply migration on wrong projects. Particularly if you have migrations in some project other than Web.

Comment: @CodeNameJack Ah, right. That error is common, yeah. I thought of it the first thing I tested. Great mind think alike, right? But no, one projects only, the dropdown in Package Manager window says *Web*, I also navigated to that directory to the PWD says *../Web* and I usually specify *--project Web*. Good first shot, though. :)

Comment: Then maybe this conversation helps the next person coming here. :)

Comment: @Braytiner Ahem... That link leads nowhere. And by that, I mean that it leads to a deleted reply. I can see it because I have sufficient reputation but a general user won't. Was that a typo or what happened there?

Comment: Thanks for your help @KonradViltersten, the correct link is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617188/7890100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to refer additional packages for Migrations to work,
add:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Add it to the project that has data context.

Comment: I'm confused by your suggestion to add *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*. Are you saying I should duplicate the line in PROJ file (it's already listed in the item group, third from the bottom and there's only one project in the solution so that's where the definition of context resides, inheriting from *DbContext*). Or is it that you missed that line and I should add tools only? Those packs should definitely be included in a common, single-installation-style thingy... Do you have a reference to a full listing of what's to be added at MSDN or something? I haven't found such thing.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer , proabbly I missed to notice that you had it already.

Comment: Those thingies ought really, really be bundled so one doesn't have to think, remember and get frustrated. The excellence and strength of .NET is the ease of use. Microsoft gives me tools that do stuff for me and I can focus on the cool, fun, complicated stuff. That was the deal 2001 when they released .NET 0.9 and I think it worked out rather well. Do not go bananas on old people like me, now...   :)

Comment: I think we can forgive MS for this. Dot Net core is changing so rapidly that even they might not be sure what to bundle.  They already have one core bundle. But yes documentation for these have to improve. Many things about EFCore, Identity, Startup.cs are not intuitive. I see you have swagger atleast, that itself is tricky to setup for many.