# Your target project 'XXX' doesn't reference EntityFramework. This package is required

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I have gone wrong. I am trying to get migrations to work on EFCore with SQLite (Console App .NET Core 3.1)

Running any command such as enable-migrations or update-database gives the error;

Your target project 'XXX' doesn't reference EntityFramework. This package is for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your target project is correct, install the package, and try again.

Seems a bit weird to need the EntityFramework if I am using EFCore??

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Comment: are there multiple projects int he solution?

Comment: it sounds like there are  multiple projects int he solution and are using the package manager console. if the Console app is the one that actually has all the EF it should be the startup project and the "Default Project" in Package Manager Console. Also I would only include Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools all the rest will be include by including those two.

Comment: Also, for all of you that are using .Net Core, maybe you installed EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and not EntityFramework.Tools (obviously), so you can specify this when running the commands in console like this:
EntityFrameworkCore\add-migration MigrationName

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was getting this same exceptions because I had the EntityFrameWork package installed along with EntityFrameWorkCore. I was using the later for some older functions I had in my Library which executed SqlCommand.

Installing both packages completely scrubbed my project even after I removed the EntityFramework package. Michael Browns comment gave me a hint as I ended up having to completely reset my EntityFramework Migrations by following this suggestion:
[Reset Entity Framework](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate)

Answer (score 4):

There's another way to do this:

We need to use a factory for the DbContext to create migration in design time.

We implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface, because, for convention, when a class that implements this interface is found in the DbContext same project or in startup project, EFCore discard other ways to create the DbContext and will use the factory.

See the implementation example:

```
  public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
  {

    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
      var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();

      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your ConnectionString Here");

      return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
```

After implement this, set the project that contains the DbContext as startup and default project and try to create the migrations:

```
//.Net Core CLI:
dotnet ef migrations Add Initial -p .\src\Data\Data.csproj -s .\src\Data\Data.csproj

//Package Manager Console
Add-Migration Initial -p .\src\Data\Data.csproj -s .\src\Data\Data.csproj
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this was the strange solution and to my surprise it worked!

Just update the Visual Studio from VS installer and relaunch it. This will remove all your unnecessary packages and re-install packages will solve your EF and EF core package conflicts. Then run your migration and you will see the error will go away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, and it seems after the latest VS2019 update. I tried a repair, it still did not fix the issue.

Comment: what did resolve my issue for this error was generating resync migrations for all contexts. Somehow, this was resulting in this error via the command-line ef6.exe instead of telling me there are unapplied changes.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Thanks for this suggestion... It led me down the road to finding the solution. See my posted answer as I wasn't sure what you fully meant by Resync Migrations.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs in EF you can generate a blank migration using the -IgnoreChanges option. This updates the binary snapshot that EF uses to detect changes, but doesn’t apply any changes to your database. What you did would have had the same effect, since the binary snapshot was out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue in project that I had both EF Core and EF6 installed.

I was constantly getting message while creating migrations:

> Both Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core are installed. The
> Entity Framework 6 tools are running. Use
> 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework Core.

If my tools defaulted to EF6 ones, I got message

> Entity Framework 6 tools are running

and then I would get error message that Entity Framework is needed:

> Your target project 'MyProject.DataContext' doesn't reference
> EntityFramework. This package is required for the Entity Framework
> Core Tools to work. Ensure your target project is correct, install the
> package, and try again.

This was part of big solution (both **.Net Framework** and **.Net Core**) and there is no way to make it use only one of them.

This was happening specifically on the Core part.

What I tried and possibly what I would suggest is:

1. Try repair your visual studio installation.
2. Setup properly "**Startup project**" in your **Visual Studio** and "**Default Project**" in your **Package manager console**.
3. Use  For EF6:

   ```
   EntityFramework\Add-Migration <MIGRATIONNAME>
   ```

   For EF Core:

   ```
   EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration <MIGRATIONNAME>
   ```

Combination of these 3 things helped me out.

As others haven't figured out, but **I am sure having both EF6 and EF Core is culprit**. I documented my journey here:  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27051

Answer (score 0):

Removing EF package and re-installing it again solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package installed